# Selenium Chromedriver issue after Windows 10 1803 update

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

After latest Windows 1803 Update. We are facing issue with selenium scripts launching chromedriver.

If scripts are put for overnight executions, after some time scripts starts failing with below exception of webdriver

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver
>   server to start

Below are the dependency versions used

> Selenium : 3.141 Chromedriver : 2.46 Chrome Version : 72 Java version
>   : 1.8.0_201

Please let us know if anyone encountered above issue after Windows 1803 upgrade

Regards,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you cannot use RemoteWebDriver instead?

In my experience, RemoteWebDriver tends to be the best way to avoid driver errors when running tests, unless you need to do something oddly specific to ChromeDriver.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver

Comment: Hello @K. W. H. Thanks for your reply. We will try to use RemoteWebDriver as suggested by you since we don't have anything specific operations